# adding image to NSAttributedString makes the text not centre

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

extension UILabel {

```
func setAttributedTextWithElements(objectsForLabel: [AnyObject]) {

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    for object in objectsForLabel {

        if let string = object as? String {
            attributedString.append(NSAttributedString.init(string: string))
        } else if let imageForLabel = object as? UIImage {
            let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
            attachment.image = imageForLabel
            let attributedImageString = NSAttributedString.init(attachment: attachment)
            attributedString.append(attributedImageString)
            let imageWidth = (attachment.image?.size.width)!
            let imageHeight = (attachment.image?.size.height)!
            attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: font.descender, width:imageWidth, height:imageHeight)
        }
    }
    attributedText = attributedString
}
```

[image]

Basically the text is not centred any more. If comment out the code for the image the label text is perfectly centred.

I'm passing an image and a string "20" to this method in the array.

Comment: You need to offset the baseline of the "20" string by setting the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` attribute: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey/1526427-baselineoffset

Comment: I added attributedString.addAttributes([NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(value: 20)], range: NSRangeFromString(stringToTest)) didn't seam to have an effect.

Comment: It's probably being added to the entire string (therefore moving the image as well). I would set the baseline of the `NSAttributedString(string: string)` in the first section of the `if` statement.

Comment: Adding image to NSAttributedString?  That's a bizarre topic title.  It's often the other way around.